# What is $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$? What is the relationship between $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ for $m,n \geq1 $? Can someone give an example? What is the relationship between $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_m$? What is our 'well-known' group which similar to $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$?

Comment: In what respect is $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ iself not well-known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ should denote the integers modulo $mn$. The relationship between $\mathbb{Z}_m$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ is:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}_{mn} \cong \mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n \Leftrightarrow m,n\text{ coprime}
\end{equation}

As an example consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3$. You can check that $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\cong \mathbb{Z}_6$ by finding an element in $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3$ of order $6$

Comment: So $\mathbb{Z_{mn}}=\lbrace [i] | 0 \leq i \leq mn-1 \rbrace$ ?

Comment: @Idonknow As a set, yes. With $[i]$ being understood to mean the equivalence class $\bmod\: mn$.

Comment: @AlexBecker: yes, $[i]$ denotes equivalence class where $[i]=\lbrace i+(mn)t| t \in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace$

Comment: I would write this as $\mathbb{Z}_{mn} \cong \mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$, since the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ projects to both $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$, but contains neither of them as (unital) subring.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a nice question before about to this question, but cannot find it to make you linked. Anyway, consider the set $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$. This set establish a goup under addition in **(mod n)**. More over this group is cyclic and it has $n$ elements. We always denote it by $\mathbb Z_n$. So $$\mathbb Z_n=\{0,1.2...,n-1\}$$. From above you can easily find out what is $\mathbb Z_{mn}$. For the second question, I am adding an exampe in which you can understand the relation between $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ and for example $\mathbb Z_m$. Indeed: $$\mathbb Z_m\cong H\leq\mathbb Z_{mn}$$ when $(m,n)=1$. In fact, there is a theorem says this property as @Daniel noted. I hope you can find the difference between $n\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z_n$ as well.

Comment: $n \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$ is the set that you mention in your answer.

Comment: @Idonknow: $n\mathbb Z\neq \mathbb Z$ .

Comment: Why nZ≠Z ? I thought if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then by closure, nZ=Z .

Comment: $n\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z$ if $n\ne 0$, but $n\mathbb Z\ne \mathbb Z$ unless $n=\pm1$, simply because $1\in\mathbb Z$, but $1\notin n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thanks for make my small answer clearer. I was not online. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Babak - Yes, this has been asked before, but nice answer.

Comment: @amWhy: I was very pleased here, cause Hagen left a prime comment under my answer. Thanks for saying so. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The most pertinent relation between $\def\Z{\Bbb Z}\Z_{mn}=\Z/mn\Z$ and $\Z_m$ is that there is a (unique) ring morphism $\Z_{mn}\to\Z_m$, in other words, if you know the remainder of some integer modulo $mn$, then you can also determine its remainder modulo $m$ (and arithmetic operations modulo $mn$ correspond to the same operations after having reduced modulo $m$). It is important to note that such a morphism $\Z_k\to\Z_m$ exists *only* if $k$ is a multiple of $m$; in other cases representatives of the *same* remainder modulo $k$ will in general have *different* remainders modulo $m$, making it impossible to define such a morphism.